# How to call a method in a WSDL using SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am having an issue with SOAP and I am 100% sure it is on my end and not the web service.

I can connect to the wsdl successfully.

```
$wsdl="http://webservices_qa.linksunlimited.com/LinksWebService.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
var_dump($functions);
```

Shows me the functions so I know I can get to it.

```php
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2000000);

$wsdl="http://webservices_qa.linksunlimited.com/LinksWebService.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
$result = $client->GetProductCatalog((object)$links_credentials);
//$result = $client->GetProductCatalog($links_credentials); 
//$client->__soapCall("GetProductCatalog", $links_credentials);
//$result = $client->__soapCall("GetProductCatalog", (object)$links_credentials); //when i try this i get null
```

I should expect a large response, about 1.6MB.

I am getting:
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

EDIT:  When I try

```
$result = $client->__soapCall("GetProductCatalog",$links_credentials);
```

I get "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetProductCatalog'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 158."

I feel like I am close....

Comment: it sound that you are nor requesting the method properly

Comment: What is the content of `$links_credentials`? How it is structured? Does it recognise the definition of the type `tns:GetProductCatalog`?

Comment: check the parameters you are sending in the the request i.e in your case $link_credentials. All parameters are case sensitive and can cause internal server errors if they're not correctly structured. use 3rd party Soap API tools like SoapUI or Boomerang to get the correct syntax of the request for your wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was that the parameters needed to be multi dimensional.  so ultimately looks like

```
$result = $client->GetProductCatalog(array('requestCredentials'=>array('UserKey'=>$user, 'UserPassword'=>$pass)));
print_r($result->GetProductCatalogResult);
```

This was not apparent at all in their documentation.